# javascript - call sync function as async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to call a sync function as async without making the function itself async. So what I'm basically trying to do is this: ("asynccall" is pseudocode for something calling the function as async)

```js
asynccall doSomething(a, b, c);

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
   //doing something
}
```

the closest I got to doing that is by creating an async function which calls the sync funtion:

```js
aDoSomething(a, b, c);

async function aDoSomething(a, b, c) {
   doSomething(a, b, c);
}

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
   //doing something
}
```

which does work, but I don't want to create this redundant function. Is there a way to achieve what's done in example 2 in a way that looks like example 1?

Comment: What do you mean by `asynccall`? Maybe just have `doSomething` return a Promise?

Comment: By *"asynccall" is pseudocode for something calling the function as async* do you mean that the consumer expects the function to return a Promise?

Comment: *"which does work"*: I don't get it, because even in your second code block, `doSomething` will still execute synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

One way to call something "later", getting a promise in return, is to use `Promise.resolve().then`:

```js
function doSomething(a, b) {
     console.log("doing something");
     return a+b;
}

let result = Promise.resolve().then(() => doSomething(1, 2));

result.then(console.log);

console.log("synchronous code completed");
```

But you could also use your original idea, but with an IIFE:

```js
function doSomething(a, b) {
     console.log("doing something");
     return a+b;
}

let result = (async () => { 
    await null; 
    return doSomething(1, 2); 
})();

result.then(console.log);

console.log("synchronous code completed");
```

If that looks like too much writing still, then make a generic function called `asynccall`, which you can then use for any function call:

```js
function asynccall(f, thisArg, ...args) {
     return Promise.resolve().then(() => f.call(thisArg, ...args));
}

function doSomething(a, b) {
     console.log("doing something");
     return a+b;
}

let result = asynccall(doSomething, null, 1, 2);

result.then(console.log);

console.log("synchronous code completed");
```

Comment: What sense makes creating a resolved promise in place that will immediately invoke `.then()` argument? For me this code has nothing of asynchronous.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano, see the console output and the order. That points out what the difference is. The argument to `then` is not executed immediately, even when the promise is already resolved from the start. That is the behaviour according to the promises/A+ specs.

Comment: Ok.. it seems that Javascript will schedule the execution of the callbacks to the end of the current stack even for a promise that was born already resolved. That is interesting. But it still doesn't make the code inside doSomething asynchronous as I explain in my answer. If there are not true asynchronous tasks involved, the same result can be achieved in a synchronous way by re-arranging the code. So this would be bad practice.

Comment: I would not call it bad practice though. It completely depends on what the intention is. The OP has not provided context, so we cannot know. BTW, this is how JavaScript programmers use the term asynchronous; even when it executes at the next microtask, right after the current call stack has run to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your `doSomething` function in an `async` function does nothing more. If it fits your needs, then so will `doSomething(a, b, c);`

The asynchronous operation that you do in `doSomething` will not block the execution flow, the rest of your code will execute as soon as `doSomething` returns something, which should happen as soon as the asynchronous task has been queued.

Answer (score 0):

When ever I need to, I do it this way:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    // do your function
}, 0);
```

This essentially creates a Task Here's an article by MDN explaining what they are and how they work. Note that they also recommend the `queueMicrotask` function but I would recommend the approach above as it ensures the tasks is queued when the browser is ready.

Edit: I forgot to add the link (silly of me): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide (Microtask)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API (Tasks)

Comment: `setTimeout` does *not* create a *microtask*. Secondly, JavaScript can run in several environments, not necessarily a browser-agent. So the consideration "browser is ready" may not be relevant.

Comment: The Browser tends to be the primary Environment for executing JavaScript, the browser itself is irrelevant. (More correctly the event loop) handles the Microtask instead. You're right there.

Comment: As for your point with the Microtask, the callback of the `setTimeout` is run in an asynchronous manner, so it's removed from the synchronous event loop.

Comment: I would remove the "idiot" part from your answer. I repeat that `setTimeout` does not create a microtask (there is a difference between a microtask and a task. `setTimeout` results in a task). Be aware that Node is a very important player.

Comment: No you're right, it creates a Task, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do denotes a possible misunderstanding on how Javascript engine works.

Javascript runs single threaded. It means that it can only do one operation at a time (it processes statements one by one). Some sort of async execution can be achieved but only when there are I/O (input/output) operations involved or by using some particular APIs like `createTimeout()` or `createInterval()`.

I recommend you [this article](https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff) to better understand this concept.

- SHORT ANSWER:

If there are not true asynchronous tasks (like I/O operations) involved, then

THIS:

```
aDoSomething(a, b, c);

async function aDoSomething(a, b, c) {
   doSomething(a, b, c);
}

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
   // do something
}
```

IS the same (but unnecessarily less performant) as this:

```
doSomething(a, b, c);

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
   // do something
}
```

- NOTE ABOUT OTHER ANSWERS:

```
doSomething(a, b, c);

function doSomething(a, b, c) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
    }, 0);
}
```

This will not make the code in "// do something" "asynchronous". It will only delay the execution of that code until the end of the current stack (see article above). It would be most of the times considered as a bad practice or a hackish workaround. The same happens with promises and any other pattern that attempts to make synchronous code asynchronous in a single threaded engine.